# getElementsByName looping through all fields returning values using onChange event

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a contact form. The contact form has inputs, selectors and radio buttons.

**Question 1:** Using the `getElementsByName` how do I get the index of a field using the `onChange` event? Would I use a `For Loop`?

**Question 2:** How do I do this with inputs that selectors and radio buttons?

**Question 3:** Once I get the data from an Index how do I use the index to the ID of the field as I then want to evaluate the data.

Thanks in advance!

**Javascript**

```
`// Var for element
var contactname = document.getElementsByName('cf')[1];
//Get value when clicking out of field
contactname.addEventListener('onchange',function(){
    console.log(contactname.value);
});`
```

**HTML Form**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Contact Me</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contactform_Lab8.css">
</head>

<body>

<form id="contactus">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input id="name" type="text" name="cf" autofocus required>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input id="email" type="email" name="cf" required>
        <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
            <input id="phone" type="tel" name="cf" required>
        <label for="status">Status:         
            <select id="status" name="cf" required>
                <option value="client">Client</option>
                <option value="partner">Partner</option>
                <option value="vendor">Vendor</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label for="subscribe">
            <input id="subscribe" type="checkbox" name="cf" value="check" checked> 
        Send me your newsletter</label>
        <label for="sales">
            <label for="support">
                <input id="slsSupport" type="radio" name="cf" value="sales" checked>Sales
                <input id="slsSupport" type="radio" name="cf" value="support">Support
            </label>
        </label>
        <label for="msg">Message:</label>
            <textarea id="msg" name="cf" rows="10" cols="30" required></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>
        </fieldset>
</form>
<script src="contactform_Lab8.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you're using event listeners, make them generic by looking at `this` or `e.target` instead of relying on external references

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean? (What would I replace or do differently in the code) Thanks @PaulS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
// Var for element
var contactname = document.getElementsByName("cf");
//Get value when clicking out of field
Array.prototype.slice.call(contactname).forEach(function(elem, index) {
  elem.addEventListener("change",function(event) {
    // `log` `elem` `index` , `id` , `value`
    console.log(index, event.target.id, event.target.value);
  }, false);
});
```

```html
<form id="contactus">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input id="name" type="text" name="cf" autofocus required>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input id="email" type="email" name="cf" required>
        <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
            <input id="phone" type="tel" name="cf" required>
        <label for="status">Status:         
            <select id="status" name="cf" required>
                <option value="client">Client</option>
                <option value="partner">Partner</option>
                <option value="vendor">Vendor</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label for="subscribe">
            <input id="subscribe" type="checkbox" name="cf" value="check" checked> 
        Send me your newsletter</label>
        <label for="sales">
            <label for="support">
                <input id="slsSupport" type="radio" name="cf" value="sales" checked>Sales
                <input id="slsSupport" type="radio" name="cf" value="support">Support
            </label>
        </label>
        <label for="msg">Message:</label>
            <textarea id="msg" name="cf" rows="10" cols="30" required></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: So now how do I get the correct index using `onChange` I guess this is part of question 3 as well @guest27314

Comment: @Bigboy6 At OP, `document.getElementsByName('cf')[1]` -> `[1]` ->  index `1` . Not certain if interpret "Question 3" correctly ? `console.log(event.target.value, event.target.id)` ? Add `event` listeners to all `document.getElementsByName('cf')` elements ?

Comment: So I used Index [1] as an example but I actually want to get the **index** of the field the user was just in using `onChange`. So if the user was in the third field I want to get the index of the third field. Once I have the index I can get the data from that `onChange`. For **Question 3** once I have the index of the field I need to know what the **ID** is of the particular field. @guest271314